# SQl Query with order by

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

Can you please help me to form a sql query (MySQL) that allows me to sort the results by order ascending / descending (A- Z / Z - A) and putting in the last lines that have no value.

Comment: Clarification please: what do you mean by 'putting in the last lines that have no value' Additionally, what are you trying to use to Order By. If you could add in a sample bit of code, that would really help. Hard to write a SQL query if we have no idea what is being queried

Comment: MySQL doesn't support NULLS LAST|FIRST keywords?

Comment: I believe Oracle's NULLS FIRST is non-standard SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Less error prone than altering the column of order is:

```
SELECT
  columnOfInterest 
FROM
  theTable
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN columnOfInterest IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE
, columnOfInterest
```

Comment: this seems to be the only answer that is on track and correct

Answer (score 0):

```
select stateName 
from stateTable 
order by coalesce(stateName, 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ')
```

Comment: That would work as long as there is no new state named 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZania'. :) Joking aside, you have to be careful with hard values in less well-defined domains.

Comment: That fail in two cases: When the column (StateName in your example) is numeric and for descending order.

Comment: Assumming he'd change it to 'aaaaaaaaaa' when he adds the Desc keyword.

Comment: What does it mean ZZZZZZZZZZZ

Comment: ZZZZZZ is just an example for picking a string (assuming stateName is a string) that will occur last in the list.

Comment: What if it has a space or some data started with dot, dash or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the 'order by' statement tacked on to your select query.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT HEADER FROM TABLE ORDER BY ELEMENTTOORDER
```